# AVPlayerItem's selectedMediaOption(in:) disagrees with available selection options following seek(to:) call

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm having a strange issue with `AVFoundation` in a completion block of `loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys:)` on an `AVAsset` with the key `"availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions"`, I'm inspecting the values of the available media selection options in the group for the `.legible` characteristic, as well as the currently selected media option in that group (via `selectedMediaOption(in: group)`. When I print these out, I get the following output (the array is the available selection options, followed by the current selection):

```
(
    "<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x60c002078380, language = en-IE, mediaType = 'sbtl', title = English+(Ireland)>",
    "<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x60c002078440, language = ab, mediaType = 'sbtl', tagged media characteristics = {public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog, public.accessibility.describes-music-and-sound}, title = Abkhazian>"
)
<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x60c00207b640, language = en-IE, mediaType = 'sbtl', title = English+(Ireland)>
```

As you can see, the selected option has the same info as the `en-IE` option in the array, but it is actually a different `AVMediaSelectionOption` instance since the address differs. This is occurring immediately following a state change on the `AVPlayerItem` object, in case that affects anything. Does the selected option get updated later? Has anyone ever seem something like this?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the answer is that the identity of the `AVMediaSelectionGroup` (as well as the `AVMediaSelectionOptions` that it contains) changes with every call to `.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic:)`. This means that even though the group will contain all the same information, it will not be the same instance as the one from the previous call.